# Fat/Uber JARs and upgrading cloudera 5.16.x to cloudera 6.x/7.x

Tags: apache-spark, upgrade, cloudera, fatjar

we are currently on cloudera 5.16.x and would be upgrading to cloudera 6.x/7.x. In the current environment we have a few spark applications which are Fat/Uber jars.

Will they be able to work once we upgrade to cloudera 6.x/7.x as i have heard the cloudera consultant advised against the Fat/Uber jars?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [this article](https://www.google.com/amp/s/product.hubspot.com/blog/the-fault-in-our-jars-why-we-stopped-building-fat-jars%3fhs_amp=true) there are some disadvantages working with FAT file.